# Transaction does not get processed

Tags: pending-transactions, sendrawtransaction

I am using a local testnet.
I send transactions with **eth_sendRawTransaction** but unfortunately sometimes the transaction pass and sometimes not.

When it does not pass I have two things happening at the same time:

1. I cannot get a transaction receipt, that is the **eth_getTransactionReceipt** returns **null**
2. If I resubmit the transaction then I got the **known transaction** error.

What is happening? What could be a possible solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my problem. I was submitting transaction with **nonce=1** in some case and **nonce=0** in some other. The case with **nonce=1** cannot go forward because the case with **nonce=0** need to be treated first. Hence the blocking.

Answer (score 0):

In that case -

1. put higher gas value for next transaction  Or
2. retrieve the current nonce then put nonce=currentNonce+1 for further
   transactions